# Read current console input before Enter

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I'm writing a multithreaded socket chat. Is there any way to get the console input at a given time before the user has hit enter?

Let's say I'm typing a message, and while I'm typing it, the server sends a message to me. The server's message will get printed right after the message I'm currently writing.

How it looks:

```
Me>Hey!
Server>Heya!
Me>How are yServer>Hello!
```

If possible, I want to save the "How are y" string, remove it and paste it again after the server output:

```
Me>Hey!
Server>Heya!
Server>Hello!
Me>How are y
```

Comment: how are you storing the incoming messages? I am assuming you would have some sort of queue?

Answer (score 2):

your problems boils down to two separate issues. number one is reading input from stdin or console character by character. this is tricky by itself, since most common approaches to reading input only do entire lines.

the second issues you're facing is going back and forth on the screenm because you have to update the current input and the new incoming messages this is quite possible, but the way to do it depends heavily on your terminal type and it's capabilities:

```
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43945/whats-the-difference-between-various-term-variables
```

doing this correctly for all possible $TERM values on all OSs is rather tricky as well. you might do better using a library such as jcurses:

```
https://github.com/sunhong/jcurses
```

that abstracts this away from you.

Comment: Just to be clear, reading character-by-character from a `java.io.Reader` such as `System.in` is trivial. The tricky-part is getting the _operating system_ to not buffer the standard input line-by-line.  Learning what jcurses can do is on my to-do someday list.  If it can turn off the operating system's line editor for both Windows and Linux, then Yay!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was hoping there would be a simpler way though as I'm not planning to use curses for this small program.